# Override Autofac registration - Integration tests with DI

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, integration-testing, autofac

I write integration tests for my application, and use my container for this. I want to be able to register all the components as I do in real running, and then override some of the components and switch them to use stubs  implementations.

I wouldn't want to seperate the DI and have a container for tests only because I want to test the real thing.

Doing this also seems ugly:

```
public class MyRegistrations
{
     public static RegisterAll(bool isInTest= false)
     {
           if (isTest) 
           {
             // Register test fakes
            }
            else
                  // Register real components
      }
}
```

So I thought of overriding registrations in my test enviorment. How should it be done?

Any other better ways for achieving my goal?

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you want to mock components as part of your integration test? Aren't you looking for end-to-end functionality of your application which you won't get with a fake component? Even if this means writing to an actual database instance or a WCF end-point etc.

Comment: @StephenRoss There are cases where it is very hard to simulate a specific situation in an integration test, but you want to test it as a part of integration test; For example C&C agent which alerts when the disc is full to the C&C server.

Comment: @OldFox If that were an integration test performed on my application I'd still want to load the disk to the max. You (should) already be testing in a unit test that the interaction is handled correctly, but you are now checking to make sure that everything works end-to-end correctly (correctly integrated). If this means writing 10Gb of blank data to the disk for a test then so be it, otherwise how else would we know that we are handling the (I expect) event correctly and at the correct time etc.

Comment: @StephenRoss The example of the disc is full was given show scenario where there are too many dependencies... When the disc is full the build server/test runner may not run as expected. Yes, you should cover it with UT as well... By definition integration test is where you combine several modules together and test them as a group, so there is nothing wrong with isolate them from some of their dependencies. I offer you to read more about the [Test Pyramid](https://www.google.co.il/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=test+pyramid&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VFYGV8CKFrKo8weFhrXQCg)

Comment: @OldFox I don't disagree with your expectations of Integration Tests. The issue that I feel with this is that mocking within your integration removes the ability to fully exercise the functionality in it's normal run-time environment (without caring if it is the integration of sub-systems or as the system as a whole). Your answer covers what the OP was looking for I just wondered why they wanted to do this in the first place.

Comment: @StephenRoss Well I don't know the initiative behind the OP's question I just gave an example where someone should do something like this....

Comment: My system is interacting with external systems, handles Tcp communication and other end points which I can't/don't know how to stimulate in a test. For example my application sends a letter to another end point, so I want to mock the deepest part where sending happens, same goes for my SignalR (Web sockets abstraction) implementation. If you have any suggestions to how to test such thing without mocks, I'll be super happy if you share the knowledge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Autofac will use the last registered component as the default provider
>   of that service

[From the AutoFac documation.](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#default-registrations)

In your arrange/setup/testInit phase register the mocks, then resolve the SUT:

```
[SetUp]
public void TestInit()
{
    Mock<IFoo> mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    builder.RegisterInstance(mock.object).As<IFoo>();
    ...
    ...
    _target = builder.Resolve<The component>();
}
```

Note:

Singletons, static members and SingletonLifestyle(registration) may cause some troubles....

Comment: Thanks, that will do life easy, but what do you mean by saying that singletons will be problematic? Almost all of my application's components are singletons

Comment: @S.Peter I read the your comment in the question, you probably won't face the problems I meant; Some of your Singletons might hold some references to objects which you to mock them in scenario X but not in Y. Those problems usually exist in web services...

Answer (score 1):

Well, for example you can create a static action method inside your composition root to alter the current configuration and call it during testing. For example:

```
public class CompositionRoot
{
    public static Action<IContainer> OverrideContainer = c => { };

    internal static IContainer CreateContainer()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        /// etc. etc.

        var container = builder.Build();

        OverrideContainer(container);

        return container;
    }
}
```

After that you can create a mock of you server, for example, like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ConfigurationControllerFixture : BaseServer
{
    [Test]
    public async Task verify_should_get_data()
    {
        var response = await GetAsync(Uri);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }

    protected override string Uri
    {
        get { return "api/configuration"; }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseServer
{
    protected TestServer Server;
    protected abstract string Uri { get; }

    protected virtual void OverrideConfiguration()
    {
        CompositionRoot.OverrideContainer = c =>
        {
            // new autofac configuration
            cb.Update(c);
        };

        AppStartup.OverrideConfiguration = c =>
        {
            // same as explained, but for HttpConfiguration
        };
    }
}

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    OverrideConfiguration();

    Server = Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer.Create(app =>
    {
       var startup = new AppStartup();
            startup.Configuration(app);
    });

    PostSetup(Server);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write integration test from API to database you can use XUnit. XUnit use TestHost and WebApplicationFactory to create a System under test. With XUnit, it's very easy to mock a test service by add test service to service collection.

I made a open source project use XUnit to test my API work with mySQL database. Please visit here for example https://gitlab.com/quorion-group/quorion-backend-crm