# Overriding AutoFac Registrations for unit testing entry point of application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, autofac

Attempting to write tests for the entry of my application under specific error conditions - the entry looks similar too:

IFoo.cs

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoStuff();
}
```

Foo.cs

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{    
    void DoStuff()
    {
        // Do some things
    }
}
```

AThing.cs

```
public class AThing
{

    private readonly IFoo _iFoo;

    public AThing(IFoo iFoo)
    {
        _iFoo = iFoo;
    }

    public void Whatever()
    {
        _iFoo.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

AutoFacConfig.cs

```
public class AutofacConfig
{
    private static IContainer _container;

    public static IContainer Container
    {
        get { return _container; }
    }

    public static void IoCConfiguration()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Registrations...
        builder.RegisterType<AThing>();
        builder.RegisterType<Foo>().AsImplementedInterfaces();

        _container = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AutofacConfig.IoCConfiguration();
            using (var scope = AutofacConfig.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var aThing = scope.Resolve<AThing>();
                var result = aThing.Whatever());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Test.cs

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldReturn0WhenExceptionEncountered()
    {
        // How to override say, Foo.DoStuff to throw an exception?
        var result = Program.Main();

        Assert(0, result);
    }
}
```

The above is an oversimplified example, however it can be difficult to actually cause an exception through my real implementations that are registered through AutoFac.  In order to test the entry point's catching of exceptions, it would be easier if i could inject a mock or fake of one of my dependencies within `Foo`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36472394/2312877) I have made the following changes to test my scenario:

Refactored AutoFacConfig.cs

```
public class AutofacConfig
{
    private static IContainer _container;

    public static Action<ContainerBuilder> OverridenRegistrations;

    public static IContainer Container
    {
        get { return _container; }
    }
    public static void IoCConfiguration()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Registrations...
        builder.RegisterType<AThing>();
        builder.RegisterType<Foo>().AsImplementedInterfaces();

        OverridenRegistrations(builder);

        _container = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Refactored Test.cs

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{

    public class ExceptionFoo : IFoo
    {
        public void DoStuff()
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldReturn0WhenExceptionEncountered()
    {
        AutofacConfig.OverridenRegistrations = builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterType<ExceptionFoo>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        };

        var result = Program.Main();

        Assert(0, result);
    }
}
```

Our AutoFac config in the linked question/answer seemed different due to the levels of encapsulation, so this is what worked for me.

Comment: I think that adding a functionality only to by used during testing is not the best way to go.

Comment: this does not look nice as we have to modify the code to be used in unit testing and we still rely on the IoC in our unit testing

Comment: Do either of you have another suggestion?  I'm very open to hearing other possibilities :) feel free to answer!